# congruent triangle question

Tags: triangles

There are two triangles ABC and DEF with corresponding sides abc and def. Given that angle D = angle E, and angle A = angle C, and side b = side e, determine if the triangles are congruent.

The answer is yes based on the theorem that two angles and a side of one triangle is equal to two angles and a side of another triangle.

My question is it only gives that two angles are equal in *each* triangle, it never says angle A = angle D. How then can the triangles be congruent?

Comment: What does "corresponding sides" mean? Corresponding... **to what** ? For example, is $\;a\;$ the length of $\;AC,\,AB\,$ or of $\;BC\;$ ? I'd say the last one but I cannot be sure, and this is very important in these cases.

Comment: a is the side opposite of angle A, b is the side opposite of angle B ...etc.

Comment: Ok, now that's clearer...yet there is no theorem as the one you mention. What exists is the theorem: if two angles in one triangle are equal to two angles in other triangle, and if both sides **between the equal angles** are equal in both triangles, then the triangles are congruent. This is not what you have here, as according to what you wrote, $\;b\;$ is the length of side $\;AC\;$ in $\;ABC\;$ (between the equal angles...!) , whereas $\;e\;$ is the length of $\;DF\;$ , **not** between the equal angles...

Answer (score 0):

These triangles don't have to be congruent.

Let's take triangle with angles $A,C,B$ $30^\circ, 30^\circ, 120^\circ $ and side $b=1$, and another one with angles $D,E,F$ $45^\circ, 45^\circ, 90^\circ $ and side $e=1$. These fulfill the conditions given, but obviously are not congruent.